# Random errors with my connection in c# with sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlclient

I have created this class for work with my DB connection.
Applications works fine but one or two times in a day i get this errors.

Invalid operation, the connection is completed. when running query: (different queries)

or other times I received this error.

Value Timeout expired. The timeout period expired before completion of the operation or the server is not responding. This error has occurred while attempting to connect to the server Principal.

and rare errors:

Error at the transport level when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error:? 19 - You can not use the connection nf sica) when running query

Thread aborted. when executing query:

ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The current state of the connection is closed. when running query

My db Class(resumed):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace BBDD
{
    public class clsBBDD
    {
        private string strConexion;
        private int intTransaciones;
        private SqlTransaction Transaccion;
        private SqlConnection Conexion;

        public clsBBDD(string ParamConexion)
        {
            strConexion = ParamConexion;
            intTransaciones = 0;
        }

        public int Execute(string Sql)
        {
            return ExecutePrivado(Sql);
        }

        public int Execute(string Sql, bool Force)
        {
            return ExecutePrivado(Sql, Force);
        }

        private int ExecutePrivado(string Sql,bool Force = false)
        {
            int result = 0;
            SqlCommand sentencia;
            try
            {
                if (!Force && !Sql.ToUpper().Contains("WHERE") && !Sql.ToUpper().Contains("INSERT"))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Sentencia Update o Delete sin WHERE");
                }
                if (intTransaciones > 0)
                {
                    sentencia = new SqlCommand(Sql, Conexion, Transaccion);
                }
                else
                {
                    abrirConexion();
                    sentencia = new SqlCommand(Sql, Conexion);
                }
                sentencia.CommandTimeout = 0;
                result = sentencia.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cerrarConexion();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SendMailError(Sql, e);
                result = 0; 
            }
            return result;
        }

        public bool AbrirTrans()
        {
            try
            {
                intTransaciones += 1;
                if (intTransaciones == 1)
                {
                    abrirConexion();
                    Transaccion = Conexion.BeginTransaction();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SendMailError("Error al abrir transacción", e);
                return false; 
            }
            return true;
        }

        public bool CerrarTrans(bool CommitTrans)
        {
            try
            {
                intTransaciones -= 1;
                if (intTransaciones == 0)
                {
                    if (CommitTrans)
                    {
                        Transaccion.Commit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Transaccion.Rollback();
                    }
                    cerrarConexion();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SendMailError("Error al cerrar transacción", e);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public object GetValue(string Sql)
        {
            object resultado = null;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand sentencia = getCommand(Sql);
                SqlDataReader reader = sentencia.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    resultado = reader[0];
                }
                reader.Close();

                cerrarConexion();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SendMailError(Sql, e);
                resultado = null;
            }
            return resultado;
        }

        public DataRow GetValuesInRow(string sql)
        {
            DataRowCollection dsr;
            DataRow result;
            try
            {

                dsr = GetDSr(sql);
                if (dsr.Count > 0)
                {
                    result = dsr[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    result = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SendMailError(sql,e);
                result = null;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public DataSet GetDS(string Sql)
        {
            DataSet result = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = getCommand(Sql);
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(result);
                cerrarConexion();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SendMailError(Sql, e);
                result = null;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public DataRowCollection GetDSr(string sql)
        {
            DataRowCollection result;
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = GetDS(sql);
                result =  ds.Tables[0].Rows;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SendMailError(sql, e);
                result = null;
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void abrirConexion()
        {
            Conexion = new SqlConnection(strConexion);
            if (Conexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                Conexion.Open();
            }
        }

        private void cerrarConexion(bool Force = false)
        {
            try
            {
                if (intTransaciones == 0 && Conexion != null)
                {
                    Conexion.Close();
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
            }
        }

        private SqlCommand getCommand(string Sql)
        {
            SqlCommand result;
            if (intTransaciones == 0)
            {
                abrirConexion();
            }
            result = Conexion.CreateCommand();
            if (intTransaciones > 0)
            {
                result.Transaction = Transaccion;
            }
            result.CommandText = Sql;
            result.CommandTimeout = 0;
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

How I Initialize class:

```
public partial class frmBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected clsBBDD BD;
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BD = new clsBBDD(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        clsBase.BD = BD;
    }
}
```

All my webforms heritage from frmBase and all clases heritatge from clsBase

For use BD I call like this:

```
string sql;
DataRowCollection DSTrabajos;
sql = "UPDATE tabletest SET validacion = '" + ValidacionText + "', ModificadoPor = '" + Username + "' WHERE referencia = " + ReferenciaID;
BD.Execute(sql);
sql = "SELECT orderID FROM TrabajosINBOX where referencia = " + ReferenciaID;

DSTrabajos = BD.GetDSr(sql);

foreach (DataRow r in DSTrabajos)
{
    //more code inside
}
```

My connection string params

```
Data Source=ServerIP;Initial Catalog=BBDDNAME;User ID=USER;Password=***********;Max Pool Size=500;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

Comment: what does gestionate mean? Not a word I have encountered before.

Comment: Most of those errors look like you are having intermittent problems connecting to the Sql server, i.e. networking issues.

Comment: your issue sounds like you are trying to use the same connection to execute 2 different queries.. try wrapping your connection and commands in a Using Connection Pooling is different in C# than other languages..

Comment: Also it looks like you are never opening up the actual connection unless I am overlooking something for example in this line 
`adapter.Fill(result);` before running this try to open the connection.

Comment: Rather than having SqlTransaction and SqlConnection as private fields . Assuming each method is a single unit of work, it would be more robust to create them within each method when required. If you use using statements then you know they will be cleaned up afterwards. At the moment, if there is an error, the exception handling doesn't do much to close connections, rollback transactions, or set intTransaciones to zero.

Comment: to Andy Nichols: but if I create this properties in method i can't call in same transaction to get value and execute

Comment: To Ben Robinson: How I cant determine if the problems are network? I do test making queries during 5 minutes and zero errors

Comment: to DJ KRAZE: adapter.fill dont need open a connection I change it when i see this. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c499e638-d1d7-4d7e-899d-f2de2e338241/invalid-operation-the-connection-is-closed-while-running-load-test-using-vsts2010-in-net-framework?forum=vstswebtest.
Also i cant execute two differents querys with same connection because if open and close the connection after execute connection